# Privacy settings for listing file and folders in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to list folders and files according to my privacy settings. It does not see other designated users while showing it to the creator without any problems. Only public folders are listed.

Roles:

1: Custom

2: Specific users

3: Specific roller

4: Public / Everyone Open

Query by creator:

```
SELECT 
f.file_id, f.is_folder, f.file_name, f.name as folder_name, f.created_at, f.privacy, f.users, f.roles, (SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = f.created_by) AS name, (SELECT surname FROM users WHERE id = f.created_by) AS surname 
FROM files AS f 
WHERE 
CASE 
WHEN f.privacy = 2 THEN ((f.users IS NOT NULL AND FIND_IN_SET(1, f.users)) OR f.created_by = 1) 
WHEN f.privacy = 3 THEN ((f.roles IS NOT NULL AND FIND_IN_SET(1, f.roles)) OR f.created_by = 1) 
WHEN f.privacy = 4 THEN (f.created_by = 1 OR f.created_by <> 1) 
ELSE f.created_by = 1 
END 
AND f.folder_id = 0 
ORDER BY f.name ASC LIMIT 0, 25
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bae05e/5/0

Query by assignee:

```
SELECT 
f.file_id, f.is_folder, f.file_name, f.name as folder_name, f.created_at, f.privacy, f.users, f.roles, (SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = f.created_by) AS name, (SELECT surname FROM users WHERE id = f.created_by) AS surname 
FROM files AS f 
WHERE 
CASE 
WHEN f.privacy = 2 THEN ((f.users IS NOT NULL AND FIND_IN_SET(10, f.users)) OR f.created_by = 10) 
WHEN f.privacy = 3 THEN ((f.roles IS NOT NULL AND FIND_IN_SET(2, f.roles)) OR f.created_by = 10) 
WHEN f.privacy = 4 THEN (f.created_by = 10 OR f.created_by <> 10) 
ELSE f.created_by = 10 
END 
AND f.folder_id = 0 
ORDER BY f.name ASC LIMIT 0, 25
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bae05e/6/0

Comment: Hi. can you please your code inside the question, and place it in a readable format, not one line ?

Comment: @GuyL I added the query.

Answer (score 0):

I did some fixes to the query

1. instead of a nested queries to get the user info, a simple LEFT JOIN to the users
2. changed the CASES to simpler stand alone IFS, that each returns TRUE or false, which allowed me to extract the u.id = 10 outside of them
3. used LOCATE instead of FIND_INSET, to search for the users/ rollers ids inside the fields

Hope this helps

```
SELECT
    f.file_id, f.is_folder, f.file_name, f.name as folder_name, f.created_at, f.privacy, f.users, f.roles
    , u.name, u.surname
FROM
    files AS f
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = f.created_by
WHERE
    (
        (f.privacy = 2 AND LOCATE(IFNULL(f.roles,''),10))
    OR
        (f.privacy = 3 AND LOCATE(IFNULL(f.roles,''),2))
    OR
        f.privacy = 4
    )   
    AND f.folder_id = 0
;
```